# How can I whitelist only specific IPs for DNS in Azure using NSG rules?

Tags: azure, azure-nsg

I'd like to configure an NSG to whitelist port 53 to my internal DNS server, as well as Azure's platform DNS at 168.63.129.16, but block all other outbound DNS connections.

I've found discussions (no official documentation) saying that DNS traffic is handled specially, so a generic deny-all-outbound rule to anywhere doesn't work ([reference 1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/53143), [reference 2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/19615c99-f37a-4075-bd53-c623b626860a/network-security-group-not-blocking-dns-resolution?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork)). That's consistent with my tests as well. Specifically, here are some outbound deny rules I tried that DON'T work to block DNS traffic:

| Source | Source Ports | Destination | Destination Ports | Protocol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Any | * | Any | * | Any |
| Any | * | Any | 53 | Any |
| Any | * | <specific_IP> | * | Any |
| Any | * | <specific_IP> | 53 | Any |

Here's what does work:

| Source | Source Ports | Destination | Destination Ports | Protocol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Any | * | ServiceTag => AzurePlatformDNS | * | Any |

However, that blocks traffic to both my internal DNS, and Azure's platform DNS at 168.63.129.16. I can set up a whitelist rule for my internal DNS, but whitelisting 168.63.129.16 doesn't appear to work.

Is there any way to accomplish specifically what I'm looking for? (Whitelist of specific IP(s) and Azure's platform DNS)

Finally, are there any other special holes that Azure pokes through a generic block-all-outbound NSG rule, and is there anywhere those are documented?